# Dropdown navigation bar vs sticky navigation bar?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, sticky

A sticky nav bar is just a navigation bar that stays visible even when you scroll. A dropdown menu is just a menu in the navigation bar that has the ability to drop down other links when you hover over it. For some reason I can't integrate both aspects.

Heres some code for the sticky nav bar:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_sticky

Adding this portion that makes it sticky:

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

...adding it to the dropdown nav bar:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar

...gets rid of the dropdown functionality.

Here is my final code where the dropdown menu does not drop down after adding the above code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-size: 28px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer, Edge 15 and earlier versions do not support sticky positioning. Safari requires a -webkit- prefix.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect it is probably because of the `overflow: hidden;` on the `ul`.

Comment: Yes! You're right. So, when I play with it, it shows the dropdown for some options, and shows the bar for some options, but never both. Any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to successfully combine both after some head-scratching. I ran into your same issue, and after some experiments, found out that `overflow: hidden`, as [Luke suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493062/dropdown-navigation-bar-vs-sticky-navigation-bar#comment87999090_50493062), was the (main) culprit.

I deleted that line, and added `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%` to the `ul` style to achieve the intended look as well. Note, however, that you need to add the `dropdown` class to the `li` menu item you want to add children to, and then add a `div` or equivalent tag with the `dropdown-content` class that will contain all the child `a` elements that will form the dropdown links. Hope it helps!

Here is the code of the combined sticky + dropdown menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-size: 28px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 </li>
</ul>

<h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer, Edge 15 and earlier versions do not support sticky positioning. Safari requires a -webkit- prefix.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>

</body>
</html>
```